# Why if I set "default language" in spanish the GETDATE() still formating the date in english?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date-formatting, getdate

why if I do this on my SQL-Server 2008:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 5
reconfigure
```

Where the date format is dd/mm/yyyy:

```
select * from sys.syslanguages where langid = 5
```

returns

```
dateformat
----------
dmy
```

So if I do

```
select GETDATE()
```

I'm waiting for something like:

```
(no column name)
----------------
31/08/2013 13:20:44.590
```

but I get:

```
(no column name)
----------------
2013-08-31 13:20:44.590
```

I'm using SQL-Server 2008 Express compatibility mode 100

## ADDED:

My real problem is that I need to pass to Stored Procedures dates in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm to DATETIME variables, but the parser is still waiting for yyyy-mm-dd although I change the default language.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you "need to pass" d/m/y? Why not pass unambiguous date formats? What do you gain by using a confusing date format?

Answer (score 1):

The following is going to be rendered by Management Studio, irrespective of server settings:

```
SELECT GETDATE();
```

This is returning a datetime value to the client application, NOT A STRING. If you want a string, you can explicitly convert to a specific style:

As for the *input* to your stored procedures, please, please, please pass proper datetime parameters and not strings. There is no reason to allow users to enter freetext like 6/9/2013 when you really don't know if they meant September 6th or June 9th. The safe formats to pass to SQL Server are:

```
YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS.nnn
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.nnn
```

Anything else can be misinterpreted. Which is why you shouldn't handle these as strings anywhere except at the final step of presentation / display.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!, the problem is that my application (ASP.NET MVC) was localed "en" and because is a spanish app I changed it the glogal locale to "es" so now the default date string format is DD/MM/YYYY (witch is great for me), but with your suggestion I have to do a reformating in all my calls to the Stored Procedures that uses DateTime as input, I have a lot and I have to review all the code, only for that :)

Comment: @Santiago Why do you have to do any reformatting? Your calls to your stored procedures should be using DateTime parameters, not strings. Period.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
Select CONVERT(varchar(100), GETDATE(),103)+' '
+CONVERT(varchar(100), GETDATE(),108) as now
```

the result is [image]